# Connect by ssh even if I'm not logged

Tags: ssh, openssh

I installed kubuntu 16.04 (amd64) on my laptop.

I want access by ssh to my laptop. What's I do?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo ufw allow 22
```

Now I can connect from my another PC to my laptop by ssh. OK. But I still have 2 issues:

1) just power on my laptop. I see logging screen. But I can not connect by ssh now, because my laptop do not connected to network at this moment. If I logging, then I see notification about connection to wifi. And now I can connect by ssh. Can I config, that my laptop will be connected to network before any user logged in?

2) I logged to my laptop. I can connect by ssh too. Then I logout. Now I can not connect by ssh, but I can ping my laptop success. Is available solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

When you configured your WiFi access you probably did not check something like "Allow to use this connection for all users", which means that until you are locally logged-in the WiFi is not turned on, which explains why you can not access your laptop remotely.

If you log in, and then go into the System Preferences related to Network/WiFi you should be able to change your connection to make sure it is available for all users and hence should be set up automatically at boot.